# How sum the elements of an stack using short int in asembly riscv

Tags: arrays, assembly, stack, riscv

Aready have a code using array but i would like to use short int.
how do i use short int?

```
sum:
    lw x1, 0x0(x10)
    lw x2, 0x4(x10)
    add x3, x0, x0
loop:
    lw x4, 0x0(x1)
    add x3, x3, x4
    addi x1, x1, 4
    addi x2, x2, -1
    bnex x2, loop
    
    sw x3, 0x8(x10)
```

Comment: Do you understand this code?

Answer (score 1):

Risc-V does not have any types. So the compiler could compile the same code using short ints to your example.

But since short ints in most cases are 16 bits long, also known as a half words, you can rewrite the code using lh (load halfword) and sh (store halfword) instead of lw and sw.

Also you need to take care with the registers you are using, otherwise the code won't run correctly. And also with what you are loading. In your example you are using x10 (a0 - argument register 1) as a pointer to the pointer of an array and also a pointer to the size. This is usually not done and also not possible to describe in C (maybe with structs).

Back to the registers. You are using x1 (ra - return address), x2 (sp - stack pointer), x3 (gp - global pointer) and x4 (tp - thread pointer). All of those are registers you don't want to touch for basic general purpose operations. The registers normally used for these kind of operations are the x5-x7 and x28-x31 temporary registers. But for readability purposes it's better to use t0-t6 instead.

This is a correct version for short ints:

```
sum:                 # C-style: short int sum(short int* array, short int size)
                     # a0 holds the array pointer and a1 holds the size
    addi t0, zero, 0 # t0 will hold the result of the summation
loop:
    lh t1, 0(a0)     # load the first element of the array
    add t0, t0, t1   # sum the array element to t0
    addi a1, a1, -1  # decrement the size to not overflow the array
    addi a0, a0, 2   # increment the array address to point to the next array element
                     # its 2 because of short ints (16 bits -> 2 bytes)
    bnez a1, loop    # check if the summation is done

    add a0, t0, zero # move the result to a0 (also return value register)
    ret              # return using the ra register (so don't overwrite the ra register)
```

I hope this was helpful.

For further help I would highly recommend reading the "Risc-V user spec". It also describes the use of registers and how functions are mapped very well.